Prove that a point lies on $OI$
Let $ABC$ be a triangle with an incenter $I$ and a circumcenter $O$. Let $A',B',C'$ be the incircle tangency points with sides $BC,CA,AB$. Let $B_1$ be the reflection of $B'$ over the line $A'C'$ and $B_2$ be the intersection point of lines $BB_1$ and $AC$.
Prove that $I$, $O$ and $B_2$ are collinear.


I have attached the diagram. I was hinted that the problem requires some kind of Simson's line usage. I have tried finding a good inscribed quadrilateral so that $IOB_2$ is its Simson's line but I haven't yet found one.



Comment: I could make this construction. H is orthocenter and P is the reflect of H over AC. PK is perpendicular to the extension of AC and it intersect IO at F. As can be seen $B_2$ in on FO. I hope it helps and you find the reason.
